# Google Custom Search conflicting with Bootstrap and Skipping a Line in NavBar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-custom-search

I just incorporated Google Custom Search into my Bootstrap powered NavBar. Some weird formatting occurred which I fixed by adding the below CSS code.

This fixed many of the issues but there is still one left: the search box forces a line skip within my NavBar.
[image: Screenshot of line-skip]

Below is my HTML and CSS code.

**HTML code (basically the bootstrap template replacing their search form with Google's):**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>



      <!-- Google search -->
      <!-- <gcse:search></gcse:search> -->
      <div style="width: 20%;">
       <gcse:search></gcse:search>
      </div>

      <!-- Bootstrap search -->
      <!-- <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Android Term">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </form> -->



      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS code**

```
/* AM22 - To make google search box appear correct */
input.gsc-input, .gsc-input-box, .gsc-input-box-hover, .gsc-input-box-focus, .gsc-search-button 
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    line-height: normal;
}

/* AM22 - To make google search results tabs appear correct */
.gsc-tabsArea div 
{
    /*By default, Google custom search CSS sets it as AUTO, which shows scroll bars*/
    overflow: visible; 
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I tried a few variations of the nowrap attribute, the nobr tag and white-space: nowrap; but none of these worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: without seeing your real rendered code is difficult to say, but I'd bet you either have a `clear:both` or `display:block` declaration. Either way, keep in mind that you're using `gsce:search` when you need to use `gsce:searchbox` or your search results will be displayed in your nav bar

Comment: The gsce:search is what was automatically generated when I made it on Google and seems to be working (generates results correctly.) If I change it to gsce:searchbox it completely disappears.

How would I undo the clear:both or display:block? Would display:inline work?

Edit: I tried various combinations of altering the display and clear properties but neither seemed to work.

Edit2: Here is the code I tried

    <div class=".nowrap" style="width: 20% !important; display: inline-flex !important; clear: none !important;">
          <gcse:search></gcse:search>
          </div>

Comment: When you change to gsce:searcbox, you'll also need to add a gcse:searchresults element somewhere else on the page to SHOW the search results. Check out my implementation I have so far: http://test.wrestlestat.com

Answer (score 0):

For my website (link in my comment above) I placed the search box in the `<div class="navbar-header">`

I believe I also had to manually set the width so it wasn't full-page width.

Now about styling my version...